# OneToOne retornando valor errado

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Galera me ajudem por favor, estou com um problema aqui e estou batendo a cabeça pra resolver isso faz horas.
Uso Spring no projeto e tenho o seguinte relacionamento em um dos meus models:

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "ITE_COD_INTERNO")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@Getter @Setter
private ItemPreco preco;
```

Na ItemPreco tenho isso:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "preco")
@Setter
private Item item;
```

Minha classe ItemPreco tem dois campos principais:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TPC_COD_INTERNO")
@Getter @Setter
private String itemId;

@Column(name = "TPC_UNIDADE")
@Getter @Setter
private String unidade;
```

Meu repository que realizo a consulta está da seguinte forma:

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM Item i "
        + "WHERE i.grupo.visivel = :visivel "
        + "AND i.preco.unidade = :unidade "
        + "AND i.itemId = :itemId "
        + "AND i.preco.preco <> 0 "
        + "ORDER BY i.descricao")
Item findByItemIdAndVisivelAndUnidade(@Param("itemId") String itemId, @Param("visivel") boolean visivel, @Param("unidade") String unidade);
```

O retorno que eu recebo, é uma linha de uma unidade "aleatória" e não a que busquei.
Exemplo: busquei pela unidade 001 e recebo a unidade 002.

E o que eu quero é buscar um item e o preço dele, que tem um relacionamento OneToOne se buscado pelo código interno + unidade.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz de como resolver isso eu agradeço, muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: Está confuso isso. Por exemplo: você diz que "Minha classe Item tem dois campos principais": itemId e unidade; no entanto na sua query você coloca como se itemId estivesse no Item (`i.itemId:=itemId`) e unidade num atributo do Item chamado `preco` (`i.preco.unidade`), que nem foi mostrado na sua classe Item.

Comment: É que as duas classes tem um atributo itemId pra poder relacionar uma com a outra. E acho que você leu errado a parte que disse: "Minha classe Item tem dois campos principais", na verdade eu escrevi "Minha classe ItemPreco tem dois campos principais", talvez seja por isso que tenha ficado confuso

Comment: Continua confuso. Se ItemPreco tem Item "mapped by preco" não precisaria de um itemId para mapear. Acho melhor colocar o código completo das classes Item e ItemPreco.

Answer (score 1):

Solução encontrada:
eu criei um construtor com atributos para a classe Item e ao invés de usar o relacionamento com a tabela ItemPreco, somente usei o valor retornado do select.

Construtor:

```
    public Item(String itemId, String codBarra, CbAlt codBarraAlterado, Long estado, String complemento, String descricao, String unidade, String pesado, Long opcional, Integer opcionaisGratis,
        String impressoras, String tempoPreparo, GrupoItem grupo, String cardapio, Double precoSelecionado) {
    super();
    this.itemId = itemId;
    this.codBarra = codBarra;
    this.codBarraAlterado = codBarraAlterado;
    this.estado = estado;
    this.complemento = complemento;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.unidade = unidade;
    this.pesado = pesado;
    this.opcional = opcional;
    this.opcionaisGratis = opcionaisGratis;
    this.impressoras = impressoras;
    this.tempoPreparo = tempoPreparo;
    this.grupo = grupo;
    this.cardapio = cardapio;
    this.precoSelecionado = precoSelecionado;
}
```

Aí criei um atributo com @Transient no model Item:

```
@Transient
@Getter @Setter
private Double precoSelecionado;
```

E meu select no ItemRepository ficou assim:

```
@Query("SELECT new br.com.rp.restaurante.model.Item(i.itemId, i.codBarra, i.codBarraAlterado, i.estado, i.complemento, i.descricao, i.unidade, i.pesado, i.opcional, i.opcionaisGratis, i.impressoras, i.tempoPreparo, i.grupo, i.cardapio, i.preco.preco) FROM Item i "
        + "WHERE ((i.codBarra LIKE %:codBarra%) OR (i.itemId LIKE %:itemId%) OR (lower(i.descricao) LIKE concat('%', lower(:descricao), '%') )) "
        + "AND i.grupo.visivel = :visivel "
        + "AND i.preco.unidade = :unidade "
        + "AND i.preco.preco <> 0 "
        + "ORDER BY i.descricao")
List<Item> findByItemIdContainingOrCodBarraContainingOrDescricaoContainingAllIgnoreCaseAndGrupo_VisivelTrueOrderByDescricao(@Param("itemId") String itemId, @Param("codBarra") String codBarra, @Param("descricao") String descricao, @Param("visivel") boolean visivel, @Param("unidade") String unidade);
```

Dessa forma, eu recebo o valor correto retornado do select e passo para o atributo @Transient da classe Item e utilizo ele.

O que acontecia antes era que eu não estava me ligando que após o select, independente da parametrização, o relacionamento que era considerado e não o que eu usei no select, aí ele criava um objeto com os devidos relacionamentos. E como a tabela ItemPreco contava com dois atributos que deveriam ser considerados na hora do relacionamento (unidade/id do produto), o que não acontecia, pois o relacionamento considerava somente o id do produto (óbvio) e a unidade ficava de fora, isso acarretava em um retorno da primeira linha do select, que poderia ser o preço de qualquer unidade.